# Set Value on a dijit Selectbox doesn't work

Tags: javascript, dojo, drop-down-menu

I've started to work with dojo in formulares. It works fine but I have a problem with Selectboxes. 
The store of this selectbox is created within a function of the ready function. Afterwards I made an set('value', data); with data, which I get from an Ajax call to the server. The value from this selectbox doesn't change. If I tested the same code in the console it doesnt't work too. 
I made another selectbox and the same function changes the value of the other selectbox.

Here the code creat code from the selectbox:

```
var shop_id = dijit.byId('shopSelect').get('value'); 
var person_count = document.getElementById("person_count").value;
var produkt_count = document.getElementById("person"+person_count+"_produkt_count").value;
xhr.get({
        url: "./ajax_getAlterskategorie.php?shop_id="+shop_id,
        handleAs: "json"
}).then(function(data){
 var tmp = new Memory({ data: data.selectbox });
 var os = new ObjectStore({ objectStore: tmp });
 var s = new Select({
   store: os,
   name: "person"+person_count+"_alter",
   style: {width: "200px"} ,
   onChange: function ( alterskategorie)
   {
      if( dijit.byId('shopSelect'))
      {
        var shop_id = dijit.byId('shopSelect').get('value');
      }
      else
      {
        var shop_id = 0;
      }
      xhr.get({
       url: "./ajax_getProdukt.php?alterskat="+alterskategorie+"&getpkat=1&shop_id="+shop_id,
       handleAs: "json"
      }).then(function(data){
        var produkt_count = document.getElementById("person"+person_count+"_produkt_count").value;
        var tmp = new Memory({ data: data });
        var os = new ObjectStore({ objectStore: tmp });

        for( var i = 1; i <= produkt_count; i++)
        {
          dijit.byId( 'person'+person_count+'_pkat'+i).setStore(os);
        }
      });
    }
  }, "person"+person_count+"_alter");
  s.startup();
});
```

and this is the code for changing the value:

```
xhr.get({
  url: "./ajax_getOrder.php?order_id="+document.getElementById("id").value,
  handleAs: "json"
}).then(function(data){
  for( i = 1; i <= data.person_count; i++)
  {
    dijit.byId('person'+i+'_alter').set('value', '"+data["person"][i]["alter"]+"');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dijit.byId('person'+i+'_alter').set('value', '"+data["person"][i]["alter"]+"');
```

Why use the '"+ and +"', and not just:

```
dijit.byId('person'+i+'_alter').set('value', data["person"][i]["alter"]);
```

Make sure that data (key) you're trying to set with data["person"][i]["alter"] is available in the select widget already.

**Notice**: watch out if you're using integers (like 1,2,3.. :) ) as keys for your select options, it was a bit buggy some time ago.